# Serializing external node module's JSON return into Kotlin class in KotlinJS

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin, kotlin-js

I am trying to write a program in KotlinJS that converts an existing node module's API response (normally returned as a JSON object) into an instance of a Kotlin class that has a similar set of fields.

The external node module looks like this in Kotlin:

```
@file:JsModule("someapi-client")
package ext.jspackage.someAPIClient

import kotlin.js.Promise

external class SomeAPIClient(apiKey: String) {
    fun getAPIResponse(someParam: String): Promise<APIResponse>
}
```

I am trying to represent the JSON object's schema with the following class:

```
package ext.jspackage.someAPIClient

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class APIResponse(val data: List<DataInResponse>, val start: Int, val end: Int, val timezone: String)
```

Is there a way to get Kotlin to serialize JSON returned by `SomeAPIClient::getAPIResponse` into an instance of `APIResponse` automatically or do I need to serialize them manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to automatically deserialize external call. You can either consume your API as `String` and use `kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON::parse` or consume it as `dynamic` and then use dynamic-to-Kotlin converter: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/runtime_usage.md#dynamic-object-parser-js-only

Comment: Thanks. The latter approach of consuming response as dynamic and converting using dynamic-to-Kotlin converter worked. Using `JSON::parse` was throwing errors and I wasn't able to figure out the root cause.

Comment: The common mistake there is to mix up `kotlin.js.JSON` with `kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON` - former is imported automatically and can't properly handle data classes.

Comment: Can you list how to write?